# Is there a way to get Splint or a similar static checker to work with Linux Kernel modules?

Tags: linux, module, kernel, splint, insmod

I compiled ( no warnings ) the `hello-5.c` example from "[The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x323.html)" and when I tried to insmod it, I received the following error:

```
insmod: error inserting 'hello-5.ko': -1 Unknown symbol in module
```

I thought I would try splint to see if it came up with any obvious errors, but when I ran it I got a slew of warnings from the kernel headers until it barfed trying to parse `asm/types.h`

```
anon@anon:~/kernel-source/lkmpg$ splint -I/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/include hello-5.c
Splint 3.1.1 --- 03 Nov 2006

( ... lots of warnings ... )

/lib/modules/2.6.24-24-insp8600/build/include/asm/types.h:13:24: Parse Error:
    Suspect missing struct or union keyword: __signed__ :
    unsigned short int. (For help on parse errors, see splint -help
    parseerrors.)
*** Cannot continue.
```

So really there are two questions:

1. How do I fix the insmod error?
2. How do I get splint to play nice with the kernel headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but this might be what I'm looking for:

[splint-discuss Using Splint on Linux kernel modules](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/pipermail/splint-discuss/2005-January/000531.html)

It provides a custom make file to help splint get through the gcc specific extensions used in the Kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Funny.  Currently I'm sitting in the office and trying to run a static checker on Linux Kernel drivers :)

Static checkers have a hard time processing linux kernel, because C dialect used in kernel code is broader than the one commonly understood as "C language".  It sometimes happens that C front-end of a checker just can't parse ever-changing constructs used in the code.

As I could understand, you simply use an outdated version of the checker (`03 Nov 2006`), but your kernel version is outdated too, and I don't know which is older.  What may help is updating the checker to its current version, or using up-to-date C front-end, if the checker supports switching it.

Moreover, if a checker can process Linux kernel, the fact outright becomes being bragged about on the checker's homepage.  So, pick one that claims it and do your checks.

Comment: The Kernel and Splint are both shipped together as part of Ubuntu 8.04, so they should probably be "right" for each other I would think.

Comment: Take a look at the link I just found on using splint on kernel modules.  http://www.cs.virginia.edu/pipermail/splint-discuss/2005-January/000531.html

Comment: @Robert S. Barnes , yeah, that link illustrates what I was talking about: lack of support of GCC's C dialect.  Probably, that is a solution you were looking for.